# WPF Binding data class programmatically

Tags: wpf, dynamic, binding, blend

I have a data object (lets call it employee) who has many get/set methods to manipulate/store various parameters.

This object is a singleton object used and referenced in many places in the WPF app.

I am now building a view using Microsoft Expression Blend and would like to bind using Blend cool interface every of my control to the various method of my data object.

When I try it, it will always create a static version of my employee data class.

Is there a way to benefit from the nice user interface of blend to bind parameters and then afterward in the code, set my singleton employee data class as the reference to use?

best,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell blend to use a given type for design-time bindings, and then use whatever you like at runtime. The syntax looks like this:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance data:Employee}"
```

Read [here](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/ddesigninstance-ddesigndata-in-visual-studio-2010-beta2/) for more info.